# How can I delete all the <tr> elements (except the first one) in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

Let's say I have a table like this:

```html
<table id="datatable1">
  <tr>
    <th>Header column 1</th>
    <th>Header column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- Remove everything from here down until </table> -->
  <tr>
    <td>Data row 1, column 1</td>
    <td>Data row 1, column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data row 2, column 1</td>
    <td>Data row 2, column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As the comment says, I want to remove every single row underneath the header row. Or, in more technical terms, I want to delete every element from the comment until the end table tag.

I do not want to use jQuery, so this question is different to other ones on Stack Overflow. I tried some of the pure JS solutions (which is what I want) but they were too complex and I couldn't get my head around it!

Thanks for any assistance.

So far I have tried this from another tutorial but it said 'cannot read property 'length' of undefined':

```
function clearTable(table) {
    var rows = table.rows;
    var i = rows.length;
    while (--i) {
        rows[i].parentNode.removeChild(rows[i]);
        // or
        // table.deleteRow(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: Try tbody{display:none} or tbody > tr{display:none}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the second element until there's only one element left:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("datatable1");

while (table.rows.length > 1) {
  table.deleteRow(1);
}
```

```html
<table id="datatable1">
  <tr>
    <th>Header column 1</th>
    <th>Header column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- Remove everything from here down until </table> -->
  <tr>
    <td>Data row 1, column 1</td>
    <td>Data row 1, column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data row 2, column 1</td>
    <td>Data row 2, column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If I have another table on my page that I want to stay intact, will this method still work?

Comment: @S.Jones add an id to the table you want to modify so it is easier to target

Comment: @Huangism How would I edit the Javascript in this answer to accommodate that?

Comment: @S. Jones `<table id="foo"> ... </table>` and replace the first line with `var table = document.getElementById("foo").children[0];`

Comment: Sumeet's answer also gets the table with an ID

Comment: I'll just try that in my project

Comment: It works with the original answer but not with the getElementById method. Why is this? :/

Comment: @S.Jones are you doing it like this? https://jsbin.com/xavoqataxu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @S.Jones I've improved it further using information from another answer. It's cleaner and simpler now, try the current code

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first tr and replace it with all table body.

```js
var mytbl = document.getElementById("table1");
mytbl.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML = mytbl.rows[0].innerHTML;
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Header column 1</th>
    <th>Header column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- Remove everything from here down until </table> -->
  <tr>
    <td>Data row 1, column 1</td>
    <td>Data row 1, column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data row 2, column 1</td>
    <td>Data row 2, column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you explain to me where tbody comes from?

Comment: Not from your original code, you could replace tbody with table

Comment: @S.Jones most browsers nowadays will automatically insert that. You can still select it though.

Comment: Yes, tbody is the standard element indicating the body of a table. It is not required to put it in the markup, but it will be included in the DOM by browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS if you want. `tr+tr` selects all rows except the first one.

```css
tr + tr {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header column 1</th>
    <th>Header column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- Remove everything from here down until </table> -->
  <tr>
    <td>Data row 1, column 1</td>
    <td>Data row 1, column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data row 2, column 1</td>
    <td>Data row 2, column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This just hides them and not delete them

Comment: @Huangism Indeed, but he tagged the question as "CSS" so who knows what he wants. They're visually gone. Someone else already posted a JS solution.

Comment: well the OP does say `I tried some of the pure JS solutions (which is what I want)` The title is quite clear about delete, but sure maybe hiding them is good enough